# How to make Randomize function to randomize the timers intervals?

Tags: vb.net, timer, intervals

I can’t figure out the code for vb.net that would randomize the interval of a certain timer. For each a = a + 1, there would be a different interval, and for each a = 1, a = 2, a = 3 etc. there would be a different text that will be shown on a label.

If you know how to make it possible, please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i might not quite understand something like this

> Dim arrLbls(3) As Label
> 'an array with 4 elements of type label'
> 'populating the array'

```
arrLbls(0) = Label1
arrLbls(1) = Label2
arrLbls(2) = Label3
arrLbls(3) = Label4

'loops trought array'

For i As Int16 = 0 To arrLbls.Length - 1
    arrLbls(i).Text = "Label from the array " & i + 1
Next
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the Random class

```
   Public Function RandomNumber(ByVal MaxNumber As Integer, _
    Optional ByVal MinNumber As Integer = 0) As Integer

      'initialize random number generator
        Dim r As New Random(System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond)

      'if passed incorrect arguments, swap them
        'can also throw exception or return 0

        If MinNumber > MaxNumber Then
            Dim t As Integer = MinNumber
            MinNumber = MaxNumber
            MaxNumber = t
        End If

        Return r.Next(MinNumber, MaxNumber)

    End Function
```

Comment: Be advised that if this method is called several times within a very short time, the same random number will be generated by the Next method.